How to use YouTube with History enabled, but no Ad personalization?
On my new mobile phone, visiting youtube.com showed a screen titled "Before you continue to YouTube".

I chose to "Reject all" optional uses of data.  It hid the traditional YouTube homepage.  Instead of suggesting videos, there is an invitation to "Update setting".

My problem is what happens when I go to "Update setting".  The page invites me to turn on a setting called "YouTube History".  Below that setting, it says "if you turn your personalization settings on, Google will use cookies to show you personalized content and personalised ads, depending on your choices."

There is no "choice" to turn off personalised ads here.  It reads as if Google want me to turn on YouTube History, so they can show personalized ads.
Can I use YouTube History, without getting personalized ads?
My laptop lets me turn off Ad personalization on YouTube
I tried comparing this with my laptop.  To reach the screen "Before you continue to YouTube", you can start a new Private Browsing session, or use a new browser profile without logging into Google, or clear all your cookies.
On that screen, pressing "More options" takes me to the same settings page, except that it shows settings for both "YouTube History" AND "Ad personalization on YouTube".

I am not eager to try resetting my new mobile, or clearing all of my cookies and having to set up every other website again.
Context
On my new mobile, I use Firefox for Android.  On my laptop, I use Firefox for Desktop.
In all of my tests, I disabled any add-ons/extensions which blocked adverts, trackers/cookies, and cookie warnings.
You might not see the "Before you continue to YouTube" screen on your computer, if it is not required by your local laws (e.g. ePrivacy Directive), or if you have already logged in to Google.

@Blindspots edited. Hopefully the comment thread is redundant now - I believe this is now clear and still covers all the different factors? // (I haven't internalized what the best approach is, when the correct answer, discovered after posting the question, includes "I wrote the question wrong". // FWIW, I hadn't imagined some people wouldn't see the data/cookie warning.  The complexity here helps reinforce why I thought the Q&A was useful.)

The question and answer are excellent and a valuable resource for anyone coming to this page regardless of their level of expertise.

You can turn personalized ads off (or on) on any device.
If you do not see the "Ad personalization on YouTube" setting, then it has been turned off.
The setting was turned off and hidden because I pressed the "Reject all" button, instead of the "More options" button.
The availability of opt-outs is typical in most Google-branded products - if you know there is something to look for in the first place.  It is their ad networks and partners that are more unclear.
How to enable Ad personalization, or see the option for it again
The text goes on to say "You can change your settings at any time by visiting g.co/privacytools."
In g.co/privacytools > Manage ad settings > YouTube, both my devices said:

Ad personalization is not available because of your current cookies selections.
Sign in to control settings for personalized ads across all of your browsers and devices
Personalize your ads on YouTube without signing in?
If you prefer to stay signed out of your Google Account, you can still see personalized ads on this browser and device. To do so, manage your cookies at any time.

The "manage your cookies" link takes me to the YouTube "Personalization settings & cookies" page.  In this case, it shows the "Ad personalization on YouTube" setting.
The setting was turned off.  But if you want to, this will let you turn Ad personalization on.
